# Delphi Sydney 10.4.2 Refactoring is grayed out

Tags: delphi, refactoring

Rename refactoring worked during 1 hour after installation but has suddenly stopped working (the menu is grayed out, and control shift E, shows the Find dialog instead of the refactor window).

As well as control G, to 'go to' a variable or method declaration, doesn't work anymore.

All this did work shortly after installation, but has stopped working.

Any help ?

Comment: Try restarting the IDE.

Comment: Did you install any plugins?

Comment: I installed the official TMS componnent, I am not sure you would call that a plugin. The problem does not occur in all places of the code. In some places it works ok, but in other parts of the code it just does not seem to understand the code, although the compiler is successful. It is very annoying that you cannot rely on the refactoring to work.

Comment: When you talk about different parts of code. Do you mean different parts of code in a single unit or in different units? Delphi might disable some features on units that were opened outside your project.

Comment: This happens when you use inline variables, even with all the fixes in 10.4.2.  As soon as I use an inline variable, I find that Ctrl-Shift-E does not work and the refactoring menu items are grayed out.

Comment: It happens on code with no inline variables, which in 10.1 Berlin gave no problems. Some variables and methods can be renamed with the refactoring menu, others not. I have have not been able to figure out if there is any pattern in the way it does not work.

Comment: I've this issue too, Delphi 10.4 update 1. In some unit I can refactor a variable normally, but in a different unit (yes, I've used some inline variable definition there) I can refactor a property when CHIFT+CTRL+E in the class definition, but this fails into the body. Restarting IDE doesn't help.

Comment: Just tried with Delphi 11.3 and same behavior, the only way is to remove all inline variables declarations ... Another well known bug not fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. There is always something broken or grayed out in Refactoring.

One thing that breaks refactoring in Delphi 10.4.2 (I don't know about other versions) are inline variables.
If the selected code that you want to extract as a method has an inline variable, then the refactoring menu for the "extract" is grayed out.